# Capacitor Storage Circuit Having Lower Voltage Than the Simulation

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, storage

I designed a circuit to store a pulse of 8 volts and duration of 40 micro seconds. When I simulated the circuit it reached 3.5 volts and discharged.The circuit and the simulation is given below;

[image: The circuit]

[image: The simulation]

In real life, I have just made the circuit and when I test it, the output voltage reached at most of 387 millivolts then discharged.
What may be the reason for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the real life impedance of your voltage source?

Comment: @peufeu it is not a voltage source I push a permanent magnet in a solenoidal coil to create magnetic field and thus emf.

Comment: A solenoid will act like a source with impedance, causing voltage drops and different time constants, as opposed to the ideal voltage source you have in the schematic, which is what @peufeu said.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thanks for the explanation the solenoid has a 200uH inductance but I don't know the total impedance.

Comment: The discharge CR time constant is 13 seconds so, in 5 x CR (66 seconds), it will 99% discharge.

Comment: Where exactly is the "output voltage"...you haven't named any nodes. How exactly did you **measure** the output voltage...with a multimeter?

Comment: I can imagine that your real capacitors have a leakage current which might be higher than the discharge current over the 20 megohm.